# OpenTK macOS issue - 'The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts'

Tags: c#, macos, opentk

I have a simple OpenTK program, creating a 60fps render and update freq GameWindow (shown below) When I attempt to run this program, I get the response:

```
Unhandled exception. OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework.GLFWException: NSGL: The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL 3.2 and above
at OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop.GLFWProvider.<>c.<.cctor>b__10_0(ErrorCode errorCode, String description)
```

I am running on macOS Monterey 12.3.1, and cannot get this simple project to run on macOS Ventura or Monterey. Any help would be great, chances are there is something small I am missing.

Here's the basic code:

```cs
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;

namespace Test {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            GameWindowSettings windowSettings = GameWindowSettings.Default;
            NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings = NativeWindowSettings.Default;
            windowSettings.UpdateFrequency = 60;
            windowSettings.RenderFrequency = 60;

            GameWindow window = new GameWindow(windowSettings, nativeWindowSettings);
            window.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bump, still cannot manage to figure this out

Comment: same problem here... anyone solved?

Comment: Figured it out a while ago. Add 'Flags = ContextFlags.ForwardCompatible,' to the native window settings.

Comment: thanks that worked, you should answer yourself and close the question. However, now I get a shader compile error... I see no way out

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/107) (or [this](https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41---how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context)). ^_^

---

> The only OpenGL 3.x and 4.x contexts currently supported by macOS are forward-compatible, core profile contexts. The supported versions are 3.2 on 10.7 Lion and 3.3 and 4.1 on 10.9 Mavericks. In all cases, your GPU needs to support the specified OpenGL version for context creation to succeed.
> To create either an OpenGL 3.2 or later context, you should set the following hints:

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```